# How to set BAC0 to set weekly schedule

Tags: python, schedule, bacnet

I tried BAC0 for reading and writing BACnet data, I was following the BAC0 Document for performing various functions...
I am able to read weekly schedule using read function i.e
bacnet.read_weeklySchedule(address, instance),
When I was trying to set weekly schedule using
write_weeklySchedule(address, instance, schedule),
I am getting error as "data type not supported".. If I am setting weekly schedule with out time value and key value in side week, write function (Shown as below) is able to write successfully.

```
schedule = {
    "states": {"inactive": 0, "active": 1},
    "week": {
        "monday": [],
        "tuesday": [],
        "wednesday": [],
        "thursday": [],
        "friday": [],
        "saturday": [],
        "sunday": [],
    },
}
```

If I am using the following format, BAC0 function is generating error.

```
"monday": [("1:00", "active"), ("16:00", "inactive")] or
"monday": [("1:00", 1), ("16:00", 0)]
```

Can any one please help me to understand what datatype are used and, what values to be used inside week

Thanks

Comment: The used datatype is determined by the references your schedule object is pointing to (value of the List_of_Object_Property_References property). Your schedule properties should be set according to this reference. Although some vendors implement that otherwise and take the 'schedule-default' datatype as a reference. Can you show us these property values?

Comment: sch_binary = {
    "states": {1:1, 0:0},
    "week": {
        "monday": [("01:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
        "tuesday": [("02:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
        "wednesday": [("03:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
        "thursday": [("04:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
        "friday": [("05:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
        "saturday": [("06:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
        "sunday": [("07:00",1), ("16:00",0)],
    },
}

Comment: File "exmp2.py", line 119, in <module>
    bacnet.write_weeklySchedule("192.168.0.31", 4, sch_binary)
  File "/home/g2c/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/BAC0/core/functions/Schedule.py", line 169, in write_weeklySchedule
    self.send_weeklyschedule_request(request)
  File "/home/g2c/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/BAC0/core/functions/Schedule.py", line 156, in send_weeklyschedule_request
    raise NoResponseFromController("APDU Abort Reason : {}".format(reason))
BAC0.core.io.IOExceptions.NoResponseFromController: APDU Abort Reason : datatypeNotSupported

Comment: List_of_Object_Property_References property is pointing to Null
{ object-identifier: (schedule, 4) object-name: "Sch2" object-type: schedule present-value: inactive effective-period: { (255-Any-2155, 255),(255-Any-2155, 255) } schedule-default: 0 list-of-object-property-references: Null priority-for-writing: 16 status-flags: {false,false,false,false} reliability: no-fault-detected out-of-service: FALSE },

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, it looks like the object is not configured properly, in a sense that data is incomplete and / or inconsistent. Please try the following:

setup 'schedule-default' and 'list-of-object-property-references' to have matching types, e.g.:

```
schedule-default: "inactiave"
// Not sure about the json format for this one so it'll probably be wrong:
list-of-object-property-references: [{(device, 12345), (binary-value, 0), present-value, -}]
```

after you've that setup correctly, retry to wring the weekly schedule property like you initially did.

If that does not work, you can also try to setup the schedule object to point at a numeric value (for testing purposes) and write numeric values to schedule-defaulf and weekly-schedule.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,  
Schedule-default is already set to 0, list-of-object-property-references has been set to binary output 0 and binary output 1 internally, While reading schedule object, the list-of-object-property-references is shown as null. But, incase of blank value of week, Stack is able to write successfully, when mentioning date value and binary value as ("10:00", 1) Stack is not writing and generating error as "("APDU Abort Reason : {}".format(reason)) BAC0.core.io.IOExceptions.NoResponseFromController: APDU Abort Reason : datatypeNotSupported"

Comment: Hi Today I was checking Schedule.py of BAC0 stack.  While executing the BAC0 Schedule.py script two errors at line 169 and line 156 were shown..

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "exmp2.py", line 153, in <module> bacnet.write_weeklySchedule("192.168.0.31", 4, bacnet.schedule_example_binary) File "/home/g2c/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/BAC0/core/functions/Schedule.py", line 169, in write_weeklySchedule self.send_weeklyschedule_request(request) File "/home/g2c/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/BAC0/core/functions/Schedule.py", line 156, in send_weeklyschedule_request raise NoResponseFromController("APDU Abort Reason:{}".format(reason)) BAC0.core.io.IOExceptions.NoResponseFromController: APDU Abort Reason:datatypeNotSupported

Comment: At this point I think it comes down to json format of the weekly-schedule tbh. I don't know how extensively you tried on that behalf ofc. So you have the possibility to use sniff the bacnet traffic (e.g. using wireshark)? Would be helpful to see what kind actual apdu packages are exchanged when you try different json formats.

Comment: F.Y.I.  There's a misspelling of the word 'device' - "deivce".